# Firebase Crashlytics in a Service that lives on a separate process built in a library

Tags: android, android-service, crashlytics

I have a project where I compile a library as `aar` and this library has a Service that lives in a separate process. The library is comprised of a kotlin part and a native c/c++ part. How do I configure crashlytics in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap your library (separate process code) into exception handler and then use AIDL to report about a problems to crashlytic

Comment: It may be possible, but seems long work. First, i'd have to manage all the c/c++ exceptions wrapping the java calls, but i have also threads continuously running that i'd have to wrap and signals from the c parts of code. Then i'd have to implement AIDL interface when I'm currently use a messenger as communication between client and server. Not the kind of work that I'm up to do for this functionality.